# Datasource or Linq Result to excel with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, export-to-excel

i have found alot of sh*** right now. But not the things that im looking for.

I need to export a LINQ query (or the Datasource of my DataGridview)
to an existing Excel Spreadsheet. Lets Say after Cell A25

I have a Windows Form application using LINQ for the Databindings.

Any Suggestions or good Examples?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ&referringTitle=Documentation) because it's simple, powerful and works without having office/excel being installed with Excel 2007 spreadsheets(xlsx-files). It's license model is [GPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License).

```
Dim excel As New ExcelPackage
excel.File = New IO.FileInfo("C:\Temp\AnExcelFile.xlsx")
If excel.File.Exists Then excel.Load(excel.File.Open(FileMode.Open))
Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet-Name")'must be unique and less than 31 characters long'
ws.Cells(26, 1).LoadFromDataTable(dt, True) 'loading from DataTable, the 2.Parameter is PrintHeaders'
ws.Cells(26, 1).LoadFromCollection(query, True)'loading by LINQ-Query'
excel.Save()
```

I don't think that you can use it for xls-files without problems. Have a look what Jan said: http://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/253371

> No, only XLSX, but you can open it in Excel 2003 if you have the
>   [compatibility pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3) installed. If you need XLS, have a look at the
>   [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) project here on Codeplex.

Comment: Hey Tim, i will check this out and give you a feedback soon. But it looks like exactley what i need. Thanks in advance

Comment: After a few trys im very excited. It works just perfect for the Xlsx formats. But is there a Way to use it on XLS files? On our Company we still using Office 2003 until next year. And changing the fileformat results in broken Files

Comment: Thanks alot Tim. Its okey to keep that in xlsx. As you said: with the compatibility pack it works aswell with xlsx formats